# unresolved external symbol - Error using Matlab API

Tags: matlab, external, libraries

I'm trying to read a .mat-file in C++ with MSVS 2008 but when building a simple program I get the following error:

1>ex3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _matClose referenced in function _main
1>ex3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _matOpen referenced in function _main

I've researched Google as well and it seems that the compiler can't link to the libraries needed for using this functions (matOpen and matClose). I never used an external library before but I tried everything I found in Google to add the Matlab libraries. I did the following:

TOOLS --> Options --> Projects and Solutions --> VC++ Directories --> Show directories for: include files --> then I added the path of the matlab include directory --> C:\Program Files\MATLAB\extern\include

I did the same with the library files: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\extern\lib\win64\microsoft

I also did that for the project:
Right click on the project --> Properties --> Configuration Properties --> C/C++ --> General --> Additional Include Directories --> and added "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\extern\include\win64"

Then I did the same at Linker --> General --> Additional Library Directories --> and added "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\extern\lib\win64\microsoft"

So I really don't know where the problem is. Here is the source code I'm trying to build:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mat.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
const char *file = "mozart_part1.mat";
MATFile *pmat;

pmat = matOpen(file, "r");
if(pmat == NULL)
{
    std::cout << "Error: could not open MAT-file!";
    return(1);
}
matClose(pmat);
}
```

Can you see or guess any mistakes I made

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_external/f24338.html#f24607).
Go through the steps.

What I think you've missed is step 7:

> 7.Locate the .lib files for the compiler you are using under matlabroot\extern\lib\win32\microsoft or matlabroot\extern\lib\win64\microsoft. Under Linker Input properties, add libmx.lib, libmex.lib, and libmat.lib as additional dependencies.

**Edit:**

Both Matlab and Visual C++ should be either 32bit or 64bit. There are two options:

1. Find these 3 lib files from another Matlab which is 32bit. Direct your linker there instead.
2. Make your Visual C++ 64bit. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yb4317s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) how it's done.

**Solution:**
What eventually worked was option 2, using [this](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/configuring-microsoft-visual-studio-for-64-bit-applications/) link with instructions.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply! I did add these files as well... and I don't want to compile a mex file I just want to read the information of a .mat vector in an array in C++. Hope, you could come up with another option to solve that problem. Thanks so far!

Comment: @DominikKoller has the error message changed after you added these libs?

Comment: @DominikKoller Also try to follow step 5: add `#define MATLAB_MEX_FILE` before including `mex.h`. Not sure that it should help, but maybe.. Also, you can try to make a mex file just to see if the necessary libraries do at all exist.

Comment: No it's the same error message. I don't get why I should do that as I don't want to build a MEX file?

Comment: You're right, it won't help. I wanted to check if the libraries existed. Anyway, probably the problem is that you're using a 32bit compiler with a 64bit Matlab version. Maybe you could work around this by finding these 3 *.lib files from a 32bit Matlab, and then everything will be 32bit.

Comment: Hey! I tried to do that with 32bit Matlab but it didn't work out either. :/

Comment: Matlab is a 64bit version and MSVS should also be 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the Problem!

@Michael Litvin: you were right! I didn't know that you have to switch MSVS 2008 to x64 platform.

As the Matlab libraries are provided as x64 binaries you have to switch your MSVS compiler to x64 as well. I followed these steps to do that: http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/configuring-microsoft-visual-studio-for-64-bit-applications/

Thanks for you help!

Comment: great :) you might want to make this answer a comment in the previous answer thread, as it's basically the same.. I'll edit to add your link